# Do pikmin still "flower" when left in the dirt?

Tags: pikmin-3

A classic Pikmin trick is leaving all your sprouts in the ground on the first day (where there is no timer) so you can start off with a batch of flower pikmin without running down the game clock. When playing Alph's first day I left a large group of red Pikmin in the ground as sprouts for at least 5 minutes. However, they never sprouted flowers; I'm pretty sure they would have at least flower buds by that time in Pikmin 1&2.

Can I still leave Pikmin in the dirt to let them flower? Is this feature just "unlocked" later on or do I need to leave them in even longer (or overnight)?

Comment: From my experience they do still flower. However it seems to take longer than I remember it from past games though to be fair it has been quite some time since I played them. I do not know about the first day specifically though (which is why this is a comment).

Answer (score 3):

Pikmin will still grow when left in the dirt, but the time do so appears to randomized, but decreases as the number of Pikmin planted in the dirt grows.

To test this I planted a Yellow Pikmin at the start of the day in the **Garden of Hope**. I checked the Pikmin sprout consistently throughout the day for any growth. At **mid-day** the Pikmin sprouted into a bud. The day ended before the Pikmin could sprout into a flower. The following day, however, I noticed that several Pikmin I had planted had flowered before I reached the end of the day.

I paid close attention to the growth patterns of my Pikmin for the following days and even when multiple Pikmin were planted at the same time they still would flower at different times. However, as the number of Pikmin planted increased the time it took for Pikmin to flower appeared to decrease.

A guaranteed way of Flowering Pikmin is to leave them in the dirt overnight. Any Pikmin left in the dirt overnight will have turned into Flower Pikmin the following morning. I haven't done any testing of this per say, but can confirm through my own in-game experiences.

Another way to flower Pikmin is by using Ultra Spicy Spray. Using the spray will immediately turn all the Pikmin in you squad into Flower Pikmin. Yellowed Pikmin will also be converted to flowers when used to repair broken wires. Finally, having Pikmin drink nectar will also convert them to flower Pikmin (although nectar appears to be considerable more rare than in the previous games).

Comment: I'll have to try that then, they may have just significantly extended the time it takes to flower.

Answer (score 2):

If the time is not progressing (the sun is not moving) they will not flower no matter how long you wait. A couple sequences in the early game have no time progression

Comment: Ohhh now that makes perfect sense.